# C++ program to fold constants

Tags: c++

I am writing a function in C++11 which takes expressions of the form `constant1 + constant2` and folds them. `constant1` and `constant2` are stored in a `std::string` and their types are stored in an `enum TypeEnum`.

My attempt is as follows:

**Program :**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<assert.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

enum TypeEnum {
    INT, LONG_INT, LONG_LONG_INT,
    UNSIGNED_INT, UNSIGNED_LONG_INT, UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG_INT
};

long long fold(string constant1, string constant2, 
               TypeEnum typeConst1, TypeEnum typeConst2){

    if(typeConst1 == INT){
        if(typeConst2==INT)
            return stoi(constant1) + stoi(constant2);
        if(typeConst2 == LONG_INT)
            return stoi(constant1) + stol(constant2);
        if(typeConst2 == LONG_LONG_INT)
            return stoi(constant1) + stoll(constant2);
        if(typeConst2 == UNSIGNED_INT)
            return stoi(constant1) + stol(constant2);
        if(typeConst2 == UNSIGNED_LONG_INT)
            return stoi(constant1) + stoul(constant2);
        if(typeConst2 == UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG_INT)
            return stoi(constant1) + stoull(constant2);
    }else if(typeConst1 == LONG_INT){
        //...
    }else if(typeConst1 == LONG_LONG_INT){
        //...
    }else if(typeConst1 == UNSIGNED_INT){
        //...
    }else if(typeConst1 == UNSIGNED_LONG_INT){
        //...
    }else if(typeConst1 == UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG_INT){
        //...
    }

    assert(false);
}
int main(){
    cout << fold("1","9223372036854775806",INT,LONG_LONG_INT) << endl;
    cout << fold("1","2147483647",INT,INT) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

9223372036854775807

-2147483648

As you can see, the function `fold` has become really messy and long. I would like to know if there are better ways to do this.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with constantfolding and in fact, has little relevance to folding. What you are asking for is dynamic types

Comment: @PasserBy - You're right. Fixed the tags.

Comment: Instead of spelling out 36 meaningless cases, you could have just converted both arguments to `long long int` because that's what your return type is, and ignored type constants altogether. And by the way you ate not writing a function to fold constants or anything like that, you are writing a function to add two numbers.

Comment: @n.m. - Converting both arguments to `long long int` is not correct since for any two ints a and b, it is not necessary that `(long long)a + (long long)b == (long long)(a+b)`.

Comment: All such cases involve overflow, your program is going to give incorrect results for them anyway.

Comment: @n.m. - You are right that the results won't be correct in natural arithmetic. However, I would like the addition to be done in modular arithmetic; in which  the wrapped around value is the correct result.

Comment: Signed overflow is undefined behaviour, only unsigned arithmetic is allowed to wrap around.

Comment: To be clear, that means overflowing an `int` is **not** modulo arithmetic. Don't do that **ever**

Comment: I would say the whole thing is rather dubious. If it's a real project (as opposed to homework/research) you are probably trying to solve a wrong problem.

Comment: Anyway you probably want to follow the rules of integer arithmetic in C++, which call for conversion of both operands to a common type and then performing the operation. This should cut the number of cases from O(N^2) to O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `switch{}` construction:

```
switch(typeConst1){
case INT:
    switch(typeConst2){
    case INT:
        return stoi(constant1) + stoi(constant2);
    case LONG_INT:
        return stoi(constant1) + stol(constant2);
    case LONG_LONG_INT:
        return stoi(constant1) + stoll(constant2);
    case UNSIGNED_INT:
        return stoi(constant1) + stol(constant2);
    case UNSIGNED_LONG_INT:
        return stoi(constant1) + stoul(constant2);
    case UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG_INT:
        return stoi(constant1) + stoull(constant2);
case LONG_INT:
    //...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With switch, the code certainly looks nicer, but number of lines are still somewhat the same. I'd appreciate a solution that somehow decreases the size of `fold`.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to change and simplify the problem and write the code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

short int fold(short int a, short int b){return a+b;}  
int fold(int a, int b){return a+b;}

int main(int argc, char **argv){    
  std::cout<<fold((short)32767,(short)1)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<fold(32767,(short)1)<<std::endl;   return 0; 
}
```

But as you may notice if you change the short to int and the int to long the code will not work any more due to lack of continuity in the promotion rules of C++.

Comment: The type of constant1 and constant2 passed to fold has to be a string as per my requirement. This function is actually part of a bigger project I'm working on.